# Serialization of Closure Objects

Tags: powershell

I'd like to serialize closures.

```
$a = 1
$c = {echo $a}.GetNewClosure()
$c = Convertto-Xml
% $c | ConvertTo-Xml -As String
```

result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock">echo $a </Object>
</Objects>
```

There is no bindings. What's wrong?

Comment: what did you expected? a binding to a=1?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, I expected that the closure object was translated to a string object, and vice versa.